# Can we only create iOS web apps using Dashcode?

Tags: iphone

Can we create a design of iphone application in the dashcode?If yes then give me brief idea i shall be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi
DashCode is used to create Widgets and Web Apps for iPhone,its is not useful to create Design of iPhone Application.

Further details are available on

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MakingaWebApp/MakingaWebApp.html

Cheers